# Bounded function and Boundedness Theorem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

I know the definition of bounded function i.e

A function that is not bounded is said to be unbounded.

Sometimes, if $f(x) ≤ A$ for all $x \in X$, then the function is said to be bounded above by $A$. On the other hand, if $f(x) ≥ B$ for all $x\in X$, then the function is said to be bounded below by $B$.

And the definition of Boundedness Theorem is a continuous function on a closed bounded interval is bounded and attains its bounds.

But I don't understand in which type of question it is used and how to use it. Please provide me some good level examples.

Comment: True comment, not an answer: This is a simple example of the more general theorem that the continuous image of a compact set is compact, which is used in most papers that I've read.  The concrete examples that come to mind use the "finite subcover" property of compact sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two important results: (1). Rolle's Theorem: If $f$ is differentiable and $f(a)=f(b)$ with $a<b$ then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ with $f'(c)=0$. ...(2). Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT). If $g$ is differentiable and $a<b$ then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ with $g'(c)=(g(b)-g(a))/(b-a).$.... The proof of (1) uses the continuity of $f$ to show there exists $c\in (a,b)$ satisfying $f(c)=\max \{f(x):x\in [a,b]\}.$.... To prove (2), let $f(x)=g(x) +Kx+L,$ where $K$ and $L$ are constants such that $Ka+L=0$ and $Kb+L=g(a)-g(b).$ So $f(a)=f(b),$ so apply Rolle's Theorem to $f.$  Note that in both theorems that continuity of the derivatives f' or g' is NOT required.